# regex lookback get the first word

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am looking to get the first word back from a date value using regex. There isn't an exact pattern of words but I am just looking to obtain the first word preceding the date (not the entire string).

what I have so far:

```
regexDate = r'.*(?=)[w]*\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}|.*(?=)[a-zA-Z]+\s[0-9][0-9],?\s[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|.*(?=)\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}|\d{2}/\w*/\d{4}|.*(?=)\d{2}-\w*-\d{4}|.*(?=)\d{2}.\w*.\d{4}|.*(?=)\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}|.*(?=)\d{2}-\w*-\d{2}|.*(?=)\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}'

text = 'blah blah Start: 01-Oct-2018 blah blah End: 30-Sep-2019'

find =  re.findall(regexDate, text)
```

result:

```
['blah blah Start: 01-Oct-2018 blah blah End: 30-Sep-2019']
```

In this case, I'm just looking to get 'Start: 01-Oct-2018' and 'End: 30-Sep-2019'.

**Note:** Start and End may be a different set of words in other circumstances. Date formats also differ.

I did try wrapping `.*(?=)` around the possibilities but it would just return 30-Sep-2019. maybe someone can suggest a cleaner version as well?

Comment: "Date formats also differ." By how much? It's kind of hard to propose something that could work for *any* kind of date formatting.

Comment: By the way, your "Start:" and "End:" criteria are both only the *first* word before the date, not "2 words preceding the date". Please correct either that sentence and your title, or your example.

Comment: `[^ ]+: [^ ]+ `

Comment: @usr2564301 examples : '01/Dec/2000' '01/15/2000'  'november 23 2019' 'Mar 11, 2016'  etc

Comment: Ouch. Best idea: make a long OR sequence. Something like `(?:\d+/\w+/\d{4}|\d+/\d+/\d{4}|...` – you might have to hardcode all of the month names and abbreviations in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do it:

```
re.findall(r'\b\S+\s+\d\d?-[A-Za-z]{3}-\d{4}\b', text)
```

returns:

```
['Start: 01-Oct-2018', 'End: 30-Sep-2019']
```

The `\b` at the start forces a start-of-word (word break), followed by a string of not-spaces and one or more spaces, then followed by your date expression.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're looking for something like this? `(?i)start:\s*(?<start>\d\d-\w+-\d{4}).*end:\s*(?<end>\d\d-\w+-\d{4})`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c9ScEu/2)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but here's a way to do it:

```
[^ ]+: [^ ]+
```

---

```
import re
text = 'blah blah Start: 01-Oct-2018 blah blah End: 30-Sep-2019'
result = re.findall("[^ ]+: [^ ]+", text)
# ['Start: 01-Oct-2018', 'End: 30-Sep-2019']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex to match all of the type of month (number or abbreviation):

```
import re

regex = r"(\S+\s*\d{2}-\w+-\d{4})"

test_str = "blah blah Start: 01-Oct-2018 blah blah End: 30-Sep-2019"
# test_str = "test test Start:01-06-2018 blah blah End: 30-08-2019"

match = re.findall(regex,test_str)
print(match)
# ['Start: 01-Oct-2018', 'End: 30-Sep-2019']
```